# integrating authentication to my app using Auth0 and node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, auth0, cloud9

i'm developing application on cloud9 enviroment. using:

- node 4.43
- express 4.13.4

i have integrated my Demo Auth0 account into my on-dev application.
i am able to login (being redirected to the first page of my app), but when i'm printing req.isAuthenticated() i'm getting false. also req.user is undefined.

i have followed the [quick start](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs#1-add-passport-dependencies) of auth0 for node.js.

i'm attaching the three files that are mainly invovled:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    BodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    student = require ("./models/student"),
    students_class = require("./models/class"),
    // =============
    //     auth0
    // =============
    passport = require('passport'),
    strategy = require('./models/setup-passport'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('express-session');
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(session({ secret: 'FpvAOOuCcSBLL3AlGxwpNh5x-U46YCRoyBKWJhTPnee2UELMd_gjdbKcbhpIHZoA', resave: false,  saveUninitialized: false }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.get('/login',passport.authenticate('auth0', { failureRedirect: '/url-if-something-fails' }),
  function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.user);
    if (!req.user) {
      throw new Error('user null');
    }
    res.redirect("/", {username: req.user});
  });





mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/myapp");

// ============================
//         routes
// ============================

var classRoutes = require("./routes/class"),
    indexRoutes = require("./routes/index"),
    studentRoutes = require("./routes/student"),
    assocRroutes = require ("./routes/assoc");

// ============================================
//         configuring the app
// ============================================
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static ("public"));
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(classRoutes);
app.use (indexRoutes);
app.use(studentRoutes);
app.use(assocRroutes);





app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
    console.log('Attendance Server is Running ....');
});
```

setup-passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');

var strategy = new Auth0Strategy({
    domain:       'me.auth0.com',
    clientID:     'my-client-id',
    clientSecret: 'FpvAOOuCcSBLL3AlGxwpNh5x-U46YCRoyBKWJhTPnee2UELMd_gjdbKcbhpIHZoA',
    callbackURL:  '/callback'
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
    // accessToken is the token to call Auth0 API (not needed in the most cases)
    // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token
    // profile has all the information from the user
    return done(null, profile);
  });

passport.use(strategy);

// This is not a best practice, but we want to keep things simple for now
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

module.exports = strategy;
```

index.js (the actual fisrt page where i want to re-direct after successful login:

```
var express = require("express");
var passport = require('passport');
var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn();
var router = express.Router();
var student = require ("../models/student");

//INDEX 

router.get("/callback", function(req, res) {
    student.find({}, function(err, student) {
        console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("home/index.ejs", {
                students: student
            });
        }

    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

any suggestion what could go wrong?
also wierd for me that on app.js, the guide is initializing the variable strategy but actually never seem to use it.

BUMP

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `passport.authenticate()` in the `/callback` endpoint. See for comparison: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs#5-add-auth0-callback-handler

```
// Auth0 callback handler
app.get('/callback',
  passport.authenticate('auth0', { failureRedirect: '/url-if-something-fails' }),
  function(req, res) {
    if (!req.user) {
      throw new Error('user null');
    }
    res.redirect("/user");
  });
```